# Cannot send shared mailbox message with exchange 2013

Tags: exchange

I marked myself Full Access and Send On Behalf shared mailbox permissions. Then in the from field do not appear shared mailbox so i type manually in `other email address`: `example@domain.com` and click ok. Then once i try to send i receive error:

```
Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

      Subject:        test

      Sent: 2016.12.06 09:07

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

      My Name on 2016.12.06 09:07

            This message could not be sent. Try sending the message again later, or contact your network administrator. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user. Error is [0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524].
```

My Global Address List is updated, but i do not see it in GAL. Previously there was a user with same email as shared mailbox, but now user no longer owns that mailbox adress, it is now renamed.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Typing in the email address doesn't usually work in this scenario.
What you need to do is pick the address from the GAL (click To, find the account).

Answer (score 1):

In your posting you wrote: "marked myself Full Access and Send On Behalf shared mailbox" however according to [KB 3045224](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045224) you need Send As permissions instead of Send On Behalf.

Your situation seamed to be:

- You have Full Access and Send On Behalf Of permissions to a shared mailbox in an Exchange Server environment.
- You configure a Microsoft Outlook profile for the shared mailbox and enter your own credentials to access it.
- You send an email message from this Outlook profile.
- You do not have the password to the shared mailbox and do not use it as an additional account.

So if that is true please adjust the permission and use "Send As" instead of "Send On Behalf" as written in [KB 3045224](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045224).

*You might by the way found other solutions [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/292-resolved-you-do-not-have-the-permission-to-send-the-message-on-behalf-of-the-specified-user.html).*